# Spring boot RequestMapping URLs not protected when not in ResourceServerConfiguration class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I've started with the following file to config URLs and protected paths using Spring Security and OAuth2:

```
@EnableResourceServer
@RestController
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter
{
      @RequestMapping("/publica")
      public String publico() {
        return "Pagina Publica";
      }

      @RequestMapping("/privada")
      public String privada() {
        return "Pagina Privada";
      }

      @RequestMapping("/admin")
      public String admin() {
        return "Pagina Administrador";
      }

      @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/token", "/oauth/authorize**", "/publica").permitAll();

            http
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/privada")
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/privada").access("hasRole('USER')")
                .and().requestMatchers().antMatchers("/admin")
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin").access("hasRole('ADMIN')");
        }   

}
```

This works fine. If I try to access `/privada` in postman it returns a 401.

However, for the app I'm planning to build from this I figured it would be better to organise URLs in their own controllers (e.g. FundsController, UsersController, ProductsController etc)

So, as a basic example from the above I'm moving the path mapping methods out into BasicController:

```
@RestController
public class BasicController
{
    @RequestMapping("/publica")
    public String publico() {
        return "Pagina Publica";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/privada")
    public String privada() {
        return "Pagina Privada";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/admin")
    public String admin() {
        return "Pagina Administrador";
    }
}
```

But leaving the security stuff in the ResourceServerConfiguration:

```
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter
{

      @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/token", "/oauth/authorize**", "/publica").permitAll();

            http
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/privada")
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/privada").access("hasRole('USER')")
                .and().requestMatchers().antMatchers("/admin")
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin").access("hasRole('ADMIN')");
        }   

}
```

But now when I restart the app (in-memory access tokens destroyed) then go to `/privada` it returns `Pagina Privada` which is Spanish I think for "Private page" :) There was no access token required anyway, which is not what I wanted. It should return a 401 as it did before when it was all within the same class. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
```

annotations to your ResourceServerConfiguration  class and 
extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` instead of `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Seems to have broken my tests: `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Order on WebSecurityConfigurers must be unique. Order of 100 was already used on profesorp.oauth2.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1ecaf13f@6ddee60f, so it cannot be used on profesorp.oauth2.ResourceServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$80...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have below in the configure method you override

```
.authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/context"))

.antMatchers("/context/**").fullyAuthenticated();
```